# Fail to Read Through Shared Memory

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I am trying to publish some random things over shared memory; and for some weird reason, the reader doesn't pick up what the sender has written

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <cstdio>

class SHM {
    volatile char* _ptr;
public:
    SHM() {
        const auto handle = shm_open("myTest", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
        const auto size =  4 * 1024 * 1024;
        if (-1 == ftruncate(handle, size)) {
            throw;
        }
        _ptr = (volatile char*)mmap(0,size , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, handle, 0);

        if(_ptr == MAP_FAILED){
            throw;
        }

                int rc = fchmod(handle, 0666);
                if (rc == -1) {
            throw;
                }
    }

    bool read(uint64_t& magic, uint64_t& time) {
        const uint64_t newVal = *(uint64_t*)_ptr;
        if (newVal != magic) {
            magic = newVal;
            printf("value changed!!!\n");
            time = *(uint64_t*)(_ptr + sizeof(magic));
            return true;
        }
        //printf("old value: %lu\n", newVal);
        return false;
    }

    void publish(const uint64_t time) {
        __sync_fetch_and_add((uint64_t*)_ptr, time);
        __sync_synchronize();
        *(uint64_t*)(_ptr + sizeof(uint64_t)) = time;
    }
};
```

Here is the sender:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include "shm.h"

int main() {
    SHM shm;
    timespec t;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        if (0 == clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t)) {
            const uint64_t v = t.tv_sec * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 + t.tv_nsec;
            shm.publish(v);
            printf("published %lu\n", v);
            usleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the reader:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "shm.h"

int main() {
    SHM shm;
    uint64_t magic = 0;
    uint64_t t = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (shm.read(magic, t)) {
            printf("%lu, %lu\n", magic, t);
        }
    }
}
```

If I restart the reader, the reader is indeed able to read the last value that the sender has written.

However, if I start the reader first, and then the sender, all the values the sender writes aren't picked up by the reader.

To make this even weirder, if I uncomment the printf statement in SHM::read(), then the reader is able to pick up sometimes.

Any idea?

GCC version:

```
g++ (GCC) 7.2.1 20170829 (Red Hat 7.2.1-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spotted a couple of issues, however, I am unsure if they would fix your problem.

1. `name` for `shm_open` should start with `/` for portable use.
2. In `read` and `publish` the casts must not discard `volatile`. E.g.: `const uint64_t newVal = *(uint64_t volatile*)_ptr;`. Even better, drop `volatile` and use `std::atomic`.

Although there are different processes involved, this is still the case of same objects being accessed by more than one thread of execution and at least one of these threads modifies the shared objects.

---

I made the above changes. Using `std::atomic` fixed it:

```
class SHM {
    void* _ptr;
public:
    SHM() {
        const auto handle = shm_open("/myTest", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
        const auto size =  4 * 1024 * 1024;
        if (-1 == ftruncate(handle, size))
            throw;

        _ptr = mmap(0,size , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, handle, 0);

        if(_ptr == MAP_FAILED)
            throw;
    }

    bool read(uint64_t& magic, uint64_t& time) {
        auto p = static_cast<std::atomic<uint64_t>*>(_ptr);
        const uint64_t newVal = p[0];
        if (newVal != magic) {
            magic = newVal;
            printf("value changed!!!\n");
            time = p[1];
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void publish(const uint64_t time) {
        auto p = static_cast<std::atomic<uint64_t>*>(_ptr);
        p[0] += time;
        p[1] = time;
    }
};

void sender() {
    SHM shm;
    timespec t;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        if (0 == clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t)) {
            const uint64_t v = t.tv_sec * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 + t.tv_nsec;
            shm.publish(v);
            printf("published %lu\n", v);
            usleep(100);
        }
    }
}

void reader() {
    SHM shm;
    uint64_t magic = 0;
    uint64_t t = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (shm.read(magic, t)) {
            printf("%lu, %lu\n", magic, t);
        }
    }
}

int main(int ac, char**) {
    if(ac > 1)
        reader();
    else
        sender();
}
```

With `std::atomic` you can have more control. E.g.:

```
struct Data {
    std::atomic<uint64_t> time;
    std::atomic<uint64_t> generation;
};

// ...

    bool read(uint64_t& generation, uint64_t& time) {
        auto data = static_cast<Data*>(_ptr);

        auto new_generation = data->generation.load(std::memory_order_acquire); // 1. Syncronizes with (2).
        if(generation == new_generation)
            return false;

        generation = new_generation;
        time = data->time.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        printf("value changed!!!\n");
        return true;
    }

    void publish(const uint64_t time) {
        auto data = static_cast<Data*>(_ptr);

        data->time.store(time, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        data->generation.fetch_add(time, std::memory_order_release);  // 2. (1) Synchronises with this store.
    }
```

Comment: #2 is indeed the issue -- compiler probably optimized out `const uint64_t newVal = *(uint64_t*)_ptr`.  I wonder up to which point I can stop using volatile qualifier because I thought declaring `volatile char* _ptr` is sufficient to tell the compiler not to optimize out the access to `_ptr` as `_ptr` has a qualifier volatile.  Hope you can share some light.  For #1, why starting / is portable?  Thanks!

Comment: @HCSF #1 See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html, second paragraph.

Comment: @HCSF #1 http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html: _If name begins with the <slash> character, then processes calling shm_open() with the same value of name refer to the same shared memory object, as long as that name has not been removed._

Comment: @HCSF #2 If you cast to `(uint64_t volatile*)` consistently everywhere it accesses `_ptr` it also works as expected. But `std::atomic` is the right way to do it.

Comment: thanks for providing an example.  What if _ptr is pointed a C struct (instead of uint64_t)? `auto p = static_cast<std::atomic<S*>*>(_ptr); auto v = p->load();` and then access the fields v? The load() likely generates an implicit lock if S is large right?  If I stick with `auto p = static_cast<volatile S*>(_ptr);`, it seems like an implicit lock won't be generated, right?  Just trying to find a solution that has a lower latency impact.  If yes, do I need to declare all fields in S volatile as well?  As it seems like compiler doesn't inherently respect `volatile` when I access _ptr. thx

Comment: @HCSF I advise you against using `volatile` for multi-threading/processing ever. http://isvolatileusefulwiththreads.com/

Comment: @HCSF Lock a process-shared mutex or spin-lock, read/write the structure, release. No need for volatile or `atomic`.

Comment: Right.  I agree that volatile should not be used for synchronizing between threads as it won't work (unlike volatile in Java).  Tho, in my case, I was trying to use volatile for communicating between 2 processes over shared memory.  I thought that volatile is [the recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819095/concurrency-atomic-and-volatile-in-c11-memory-model)

Comment: @HCSF It is still the case of sharing memory between two different threads. Doesn't make difference here whether threads are from the same process or not.

Comment: So after C++11, std::atomic should be used instead of volatile for dealing with mapped shared memory?